# Multiple xslt inside a jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xslt

I am currently stuck at my work. I have a jsp that calls another jsp that calls multiple xml for xslt purpose.

I've tried my XSLTs and they all work. But not inside my JSP. Only the first one works then...

Here are the rules :

- I have to use xslt even if all will be simpler in Java.
- I need two paramaters from the first XML I import, one will indicate wher I can find the second XML, the second will be needed by the third xslt for choosing the nodes to transform.

I don't post the first xsl and xml because they work perfectly fine. The others work separately but not when called by the jsp.

XML 2

```
<Local>
    <Id>c1021585</Id>
    <Name>Nom</Name>
    <Adress></Adress>
    <PostalCode></PostalCode>
    <City>City</City>
    <Description><![CDATA[]]></Description>
</Local>
```

XML 3

```
<Articles>
  <Article>
    <Title>Titre de l'inititive locale</Title>
    <Url>https://extranet_elus/publication/Pages/1awpt5kkei2.aspx</Url>
    <ShortName>1awpt5kkei3</ShortName>
    <ThumbNail>http://referentiel.nouvelobs.com/file/14954208.png</ThumbNail>
    <CatchPhrase><![CDATA[voici notre initiative]]></CatchPhrase>
    <Content><![CDATA[contenu HTML voici notre initiative]]></Content>
    <StartDate>1987/03/29</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2099/07/10</EndDate>
    <LocalBank>
        <Id>c1021585</Id>
        <Name>Nom de la caisse locale</Name>
    </LocalBank>
  </Article>
  <Article></Article>
  <Article></Article>...
</Articles>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="idEnCours" />

<xsl:template match="/LocalBank">
        <div class="bloc-caisse">
            <header><xsl:value-of select="/Local/Name"/></header>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="/Local/Description"/></p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="button">En savoir plus</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/Articles">

    <div class="bloc-last">
        <header>Les 3 derniers articles</header>
        <ul>
            <xsl:call-template name="Article">
                <xsl:with-param name="cpt">1</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="IdOnScreen"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Article">
    <xsl:param name="cpt" />
    <xsl:param name="IdOnScreen" />
    <xsl:param name="MaxCount" select="4"/>

    <xsl:if test="$cpt &lt; $MaxCount">

        <xsl:variable name="idArticle">
            <xsl:value-of select="./Article[$cpt]/ShortName"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="$idArticle != $IdOnScreen">

            <xsl:variable name="newCpt" select="$cpt+1" />

            <li>
                <xsl:variable name="articleLink"><xsl:value-of select="./Article[$cpt]/Url"/></xsl:variable>
                <a alt="titre de l'article" href="{$articleLink}">
                    <span><xsl:value-of select="./Article[$cpt]/Title"/></span>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="./Article[$cpt]/CatchPhrase"/></p>
                    <span class="button"></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <xsl:call-template name="Article">
                <xsl:with-param name="cpt" select="$newCpt" />
                <xsl:with-param name="IdOnScreen" select="$IdOnScreen"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="MaxCount" select="$MaxCount"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="$idArticle = $IdOnScreen">
            <xsl:variable name="newMax" select="$MaxCount+1" />
            <xsl:variable name="newCpt" select="$cpt+1" />
            <xsl:call-template name="Article">
                <xsl:with-param name="cpt" select="$newCpt" />
                <xsl:with-param name="IdOnScreen" select="$IdOnScreen"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="MaxCount" select="$newMax"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

And finally the JSP

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="wai"  uri="/WEB-INF/tld/wai.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="gui"  uri="/WEB-INF/tld/gui.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="lnk"  uri="/WEB-INF/tld/linking.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<% String g_pagePath = (String)request.getAttribute("pagePath"); %>
<%g_pagePath = (g_pagePath == null) ? "/" : g_pagePath ; %>

<%@page contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" import="java.io.*,java.util.*,com.cavitrine.frontoffice.web.utils.*"%>
<% String idEvt = request.getParameter("id"); %>
<%
Utils util = Utils.getInstance();

String urlXml = "Adresse1.xml";
String xml = util.loadURL(urlXml, request, response);
pageContext.setAttribute("inputDoc", xml);

if(xml != null && !xml.equals("")){

%>
<div id="__contentRoot">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="bloc-wrapper">
                <div class="bloc-article bloc-event">

                    <c:import url="Adresse1.xml" var="xmlImport" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
                    <x:parse xml="${xmlImport}" var="output"/>

                    <c:set var="banque"><x:out select="$output/Article/Local/Id" escapeXml="false"/></c:set>
                    <c:set var="idArticle"><x:out select="$output/Article/ShortName" escapeXml="false"/></c:set>


                    <c:import url="Adresse2.xsl" var="stylesheet" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
                    <x:transform xml="${inputDoc}" xslt="${stylesheet}"></x:transform>

                </div>
            </div>
<%

String urlXml2 = "Adresse3.xml";
String xml2 = util.loadURL(urlXml2, request, response);
pageContext.setAttribute("inputDoc2", xml2);

String urlXml3 = "Adresse4.xml";
String xml3  = util.loadURL(urlXml3, request, response);
pageContext.setAttribute("inputDoc3", xml3);

%>
            <aside>

                <c:import url="Adresse5.xsl" var="stylesheet2" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
                <x:transform xml="${inputDoc2}" xslt="${stylesheet2}"></x:transform>
                <x:transform xml="${inputDoc3}" xslt="${stylesheet2}">
                    <x:param name="idEnCours" value="${idArticle}"></x:param>
                </x:transform>

            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any leads you can provide :)